# How do I set angular variable to value of query string?

Tags: angularjs

My URL contains a query string, for example "www.website.php?**feature1=true&feature2=false**".

When my page loads, I want angular variables set to the value of the query string variables like this:

```
$scope.feature1 = $_POST['feature1'];
$scope.feature2 = $_POST['feature2'];
```

How can I do this? Thanks.

Comment: The values that you passing are through query string, they are not posted data.

Comment: Please mark an answer as "accepted" so this question is resolved. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access `GET` parameters (URL parameters) through `$routeParams`:

```
app.controller('CtrlName', ['$scope','$routeParams', function($scope, $routeParams) {
  $scope.feature1 = $routeParams.feature1;
  $scope.feature2 = $routeParams.feature2;
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your web entrypoint is a php page (or any other serverside rendered html page, such as a ASP.NET MVC View), the way I usually get values like these from the server into angular is using the `constant` function, and place it in the .php page right after you reference your angular app. Something like this:

```
<script src="app.js" />
<script>
    angular
        .module('app')
        .constant("myConfig", {
            "feature1": "<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['feature1']); ?>",
            "feature2": "<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['feature2']); ?>"
        });
</script>
```

Then in your controller, you just inject the constant: `app.controller('Controller', ['myConfig', function(myConfig) {..}`

While there are more convenient ways than this, when you're passing query strings (that can be accesses by JavaScript), with this approach you can pretty much pass in anything from server side code.